# что задать в type, чтобы оькрыть файл stl?

Tags: android, kotlin

Перепробовал варианты с text, application, image

val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
type = "application/STL"

Answer (score 0):

Либо `application/sla` (возможно устаревший, неофициальный),
но скорее всего `model/stl`

https://www.digipres.org/formats/mime-types/
https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/model/stl

Comment: Не работают оба варианта, к сожалению(

Comment: А что в вашем понимании "работает"? Должно быть приложение, зарегистрированное на этот MIME type, его система и будет предлагать.

Comment: В таком случае настигло разочарование в Файловый мэнеджер +